# ¿Cómo puedo conectar PHP con DBISAM mediante OBDC?

Tags: php, odbc

quiero conectar `PHP` con una base de datos creada por un software de terceros mediante `OBDC` pero no consigo lograr la conexión y no puedo hacer consultas de tablas.

Descargué el controlador `DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver` y lo instalé, estoy casi seguro que tengo problemas con el usuario que por defecto coloque `admin` pero no estoy seguro de que sea el correcto ya que tampoco sé como averiguar el usuario y clave. Este es mi script:

```
<?php 
    $db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};
    ConnectionType = Local; 
    CatalogName = C:/direccion donde estan guardadas las tablas/Data;","admin","");
    $res = odbc_exec($db,"SELECT * FROM Sinventario");
    echo odbc_num_rows($res)." rows found";
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Prueba a crear la conexión en el sistema y no en el usuario

Answer (score 0):

Amigo se que el post es viejo, pero lograste solucionar?..Si no me equivoco intentas trabajar con la base de datos del a2.

Lo logras haciendo esto:

```
$db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};ConnectionType=Local;CatalogName=C:/...../Data;","a2server",""); $res = odbc_exec($db," CONSULTA SELECT ");
```

Comment: hasta el momento no pude conectar php con la base de datos del a2 ya he probado con tu respuesta pero aun nada al parecer tengo es un problema de extension de php y por eso no me permite conectarlo pero sin embargo si logre conectarlo pero utilizando java